# Hero-text appearing on top of navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, navbar

I have been working on a design project and came across an error where the hero-section text appears on top of the navigation bar. The navigation bar slides in when the user click the hamburger menu button. Some help would be appreciated. Below is the link for code in codepen:

codepen.io/davisjx/pen/WNjrBqQ

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index:2` higher then hero section  `.hero-section .navbar`

```
.hero-section .navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2; /*Change Here*/
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #00000031;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set hero section `z-index` greater then text

```
.hero-section .navbar {
    z-index: 111;
}
```